# Could not resolve <s:Callresponder>

Tags: ios, air, flash-builder

I updated my Flash Builder SDK to use the latest AirSDK 15,change the application to use 15. 
After that I got the error: Could not resolve

```
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication>
```

I the found some one else had that problem and added the /frameworks/libs/mobile to the build path I added the path and then i got a different error: Could not resolve

```
<s:Callresponder>
```

I then tried to add the MX path and a lot of other paths but could not get rid of the error. I have now spend over 10 hours all because I need to update my iOS application so it will run on the new iOS8.
Flash Builder 4.6 Premium - Mac OS Maverick.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```
-swf-version=26
--namespace+=http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009,${flexlib}/mxml-2009-manifest.xml 
--namespace+=http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml,${flexlib}/mxml-manifest.xml 
--namespace+=library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark,${flexlib}/spark-manifest.xml
```

to the "Additional compiler arguments" in properties -> Flex Compiler seems to fix it.

Comment: Now I get this when I try to debug: Also Access of undefined property BeveledActionButtonSkin.  Process terminated without establishing connection to debugger.

invalid application descriptor: Unknown namespace: http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/15

Comment: I fixed the name space it need to say 15.0 Now I get this when I try to debug: Process terminated without establishing connection to debugger. I also have two errors booth showing as in the projects mxml file line 94 but i only have 82 lines in the file. Access of undefined property BeveledActionButtonSkin.  
Process terminated without establishing connection to debugger.

initial content not found

Comment: Found a solution I added the mobile folder to the library path.